# Disable back button or set back button to close app on android

Tags: javascript, android, getusermedia

Hi I am making a program that uses Google chrome to open my android camera. i need to know how to close the chrome completely when the user presses the back button or else disable the use of the back button when on chrome. this is my code. I would like to do it with JavaScript.

```
<body style="overflow: hidden">
<video muted autoplay id="myvideo" style="width: 100%; height: auto"></video>
<div class='select'>
    <select style="visibility: hidden" id='videoSource'>
    </select>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

//Camera
var videoElement = document.querySelector("video");
var videoSelect = document.querySelector("select#videoSource");
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

//Checks for the sources available of cameras
function gotSources(sourceInfos) {
    for (var i = 0; i != sourceInfos.length; ++i) {
        var sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = sourceInfo.id;
        if (sourceInfo.kind === 'video') {
            option.text = sourceInfo.label || 'camera ' + (videoSelect.length + 1);
            videoSelect.appendChild(option);
            if (i == sourceInfos.length - 1) {
                option.selected = true;
                start();

            }
        } else {
            console.log('Some other kind of source: ', sourceInfo);
        }
    }
}

if (typeof MediaStreamTrack === 'undefined') {
    alert('This browser does not support MediaStreamTrack.\n\nTry Chrome Canary.');
} else {
    MediaStreamTrack.getSources(gotSources);
}

//Checks if everything is successful
function successCallback(stream) {
    window.stream = stream; // make stream available to console
    videoElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    videoElement.play();
}

//Checks if an error occurred
function errorCallback(error) {
    console.log("navigator.getUserMedia error: ", error);
}


// starts the streaming of the camera
function start() {
    if (!!window.stream) {
        videoElement.src = null;
        window.stream.stop();
    }

    var videoSource = videoSelect.value;

    var constraints = {
        video: {
            optional: [{ sourceId: videoSource}]
        }
    };
    navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
}


videoSelect.onchange = start;
```

Comment: "I am making a program that uses Google chrome to open my android camera" -- what makes you think that the user will choose to view this in Chrome, versus in any other browser? "i need to know how to close the chrome completely when the user presses the back button" -- why? what makes you think that you have the right to close the user's browser? Would you consider this to be appropriate behavior in a Web app?

Comment: or else i need to disable the stream of the camera since if the user presses the back button it is causing the device camera to corrupt. The user is instructed to use the chrome only for the application to work